# Random values with the same distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

My question relates to the very basics of probability theory.
I can’t understand why if two functions that have the same distribution are not equal (apart from the set of measure zero).

For example, the central limit theorem. There are the countable set of the “same” functions and their sum converges to another function...

Is there any geometric answer (or picture) why the functions with the same distribution are not equal?

Comment: If I toss two fair coins, they have the same distributions $($heads with probability $\frac12$ and tails $\frac12)$ but I do not expect them to always show the same face each toss

Comment: I am not searching for the random values from “real life”, because by definition your random values acting on discrete set and they are absolutely the same, but “in life” they are different. So how to distinguish them?

Comment: My example was designed to stimulate thinking that having the same distribution does not mean having the same value.  Another, continuous, example would be $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=-X$: same distribution but zero probability of having the same value.

Comment: Thanks, an example with the normal distribution is fine. But once again: is there a way to formally distinguish two tosses of a fair coin?

Comment: Henry's comment about the two coins nails it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Functions with the same distribution can be very different--they may never equal actually, like the example offered by Henry, which works pretty well here. If we let 1 be the head of the coin and -1 be the tail, then X which is the outcome of a fair coin flip has the same distribution as Y=-X: both assigning probability 0.5 to head and tail equally, but they are never the same.
2. We can define two independent random variables(actually as many as you want) on one single probability space, which I think answers your last question--to distinguish two tosses of a fair coin.

Take [0,1] with Borel sets for example, and let the probability measure be Lebesgue measure(i.e. $\lambda[a,b]=b-a$ as usual). Let
$$X(t)=\begin{cases}1, t\in[0,0.5]\\-1,t\in(0.5,1]\end{cases},Y(t)=\begin{cases}1,t\in[0,0.25)\cup[0.5,0.75),\\-1,t\in[0.25,0.5)\cup[0.75,1]\end{cases}.$$

Then you can check easily that they are independent by definition, while having the same distribution like coin tosses: one half for each cases. Continue dividing the intervals we can define a sequence of i.i.d coin tosses(which is a good exercise for you to check the mutual independence).

Comment: I apologize for the obsession, but it seems to me that you are wrong: the space of cases is discrete and consists of 2 points (in your case, we can assume that these two cases are the intervals (0,0.5) and (0.5,1), but then the function Y is defined incorrectly  .)

Comment: @llya It should be $Y(t)$ actually. And the space of cases is two: just $\{-1,1\}$. Here I am defining the random variables on a probability triple $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, and what really counts is the sets of their values. It is just a technical matter: we need the triple to rigorously define random variables as measurable functions, which enables us to define what is the "probability"(and what is the "distribution"). You can take a look at the first chapter of Rick Durrett's \textit{Probability: Theory and Examples} for more on this.